# onListItemClick doesnt work... Why?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I try to teach me to make a list , with fragments . I have now created a custom array adapter to get my lines in the list to be adapted for my app . However , nothing happens when I press the item . However, working checkbox as intended (?)

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

**List_Fragment**

```
public class List_Fragment extends ListFragment{

    ArrayList<Detail> items= new ArrayList<Detail>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container, false);

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Detail detail = items.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), detail.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<Detail> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){


LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View view = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

final Detail title = getItem(position);

TextView titleView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);

titleView.setText(title.getTitle());

CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.itemDone);

chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        title.setDone(true);
    }
});         

return view;
```

}

Comment: Seems like your arrayList is empty. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OnListItemClicked()` and your `OnCheckChangedListener` are conflicting with one another.

I think you need to set the attribute `android:focusable="false"` on your CheckBox. You may also need to call `getListView().setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS)` on your ListFragment.  See other SO questions for "onitemselected not working" since there are variations on this.

Also I noticed that your `setItems()` method just sets your member variable and doesn't update the adapter.

```
public void setItems(ArrayList<Detail> items) {
    // this.items = items;
    CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) getListView().getAdapter();
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.addAll(items);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

That will make your list update correctly.

(Took out my original code because I forgot `ArrayAdapter` has methods like `clear()`, `add()`, `insert()`, etc.  So you don't need to extend `BaseAdapter`. )